Latitude and Longitude types
I wrote this code when reviewing Define a class for latitude and longitude in C++ using boost::units and spheroidal coordinates.  As I've not used Boost::Units before, I thought it worth reviewing in its own right.
Quick summary:

Latitudes must be between the South Pole and North Pole, and will throw if this range is exceeded.  They are totally ordered south to north.
Longitudes may be any value, but get normalised internally to with 180° of the prime meridian.  They are equality-comparable, but ordering isn't so useful with the wraparound.
Simple addition and subtraction operations are supported, but latitudes are (intentionally) not interoperable with longitudes.
User-defined literal operators are defined for both types.
The included test show how these types may be used.  I believe they cover all the functionality, but I haven't used any coverage tool to find omissions.
There's no support for printing as degrees, minutes and seconds.  One day I'll investigate whether I can create a user-defined i/o manipulator for that.


#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/angle/degrees.hpp>

#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace geo
{
    using namespace boost::units::degree;

    using angle_t = boost::units::quantity<plane_angle>;


    template<typename Derived>
    class ordinate
    {
    protected:
        angle_t angle;

    public:
        constexpr explicit ordinate(angle_t angle)
            : angle{angle}
        {
            as_derived().check();
        }

        constexpr explicit ordinate(double angle)
            : angle{angle * degrees}
        {
            as_derived().check();
        }

        constexpr operator angle_t() const
        {
            return angle;
        }

        constexpr Derived& operator+=(angle_t addend)
        {
            angle += addend;
            as_derived().check();
            return as_derived();
        }

        constexpr auto operator+(angle_t addend) const
        {
            return Derived(angle) += addend;
        }

        constexpr Derived& operator-=(angle_t subtrahend)
        {
            angle -= subtrahend;
            as_derived().check();
            return as_derived();
        }

        constexpr auto operator-(angle_t subtrahend) const
        {
            return Derived{angle} -= subtrahend;
        }

        constexpr auto operator-(const Derived& subtrahend) const
        {
            return angle - subtrahend.angle;
        }

        constexpr bool operator==(const Derived& other) const
        {
            return angle == other.angle;
        }
        constexpr bool operator!=(const Derived& other) const
        {
            return angle != other.angle;
        }

    protected:
        using ordinate_base = ordinate;

    private:
        constexpr auto& as_derived() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this); }
        constexpr auto& as_derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }

    };

    // Latitude unit
    // Valid range: 90°S to 90°N
    // Latitudes are strongly ordered from south to north
    struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
    {
        friend ordinate_base;

        using ordinate<latitude>::ordinate;

        // order relation makes sense for latitude but not longitude
        constexpr auto operator<=>(const latitude& other) const
        {
            // Boost units lack three-way comparisons :(
            return angle < other.angle ? std::strong_ordering::less
                : other.angle < angle ? std::strong_ordering::greater
                : std::strong_ordering::equal;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const latitude& x)
        {
            auto const d = x.angle / degrees;
            return os << std::abs(d) << "°" << (std::signbit(d) ? 'S' : 'N');
        }

    private:
        constexpr void check();
    };


    // Longitude unit
    // Normalised range: 180°W to 180°E
    // Longitudes that differ by 360° are equivalent
    struct longitude : public ordinate<longitude>
    {
        friend ordinate_base;

        using ordinate<longitude>::ordinate;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const longitude& x)
        {
            auto const d = x.angle / degrees;
            return os << std::abs(d) << "°" << (std::signbit(d) ? 'W' : 'E');
        }

    private:
        constexpr void check();
    };


    namespace literals {
        constexpr latitude operator ""_north(long double x) { return latitude{static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr latitude operator ""_south(long double x) { return latitude{-static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr longitude operator ""_east(long double x) { return longitude{static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr longitude operator ""_west(long double x) { return longitude{-static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr latitude operator ""_north(unsigned long long x) { return latitude{static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr latitude operator ""_south(unsigned long long x) { return latitude{-static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr longitude operator ""_east(unsigned long long x) { return longitude{static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }
        constexpr longitude operator ""_west(unsigned long long x) { return longitude{-static_cast<double>(x) * degrees};  }

        namespace all {
            // For users who don't need different (temperature?) degrees
            using namespace geo::literals;
            constexpr auto operator ""_degrees(long double x) { return static_cast<double>(x) * degrees;  }
            constexpr auto operator ""_degrees(unsigned long long x) { return static_cast<double>(x) * degrees;  }
        }
    }

    constexpr void latitude::check()
    {
        using namespace geo::literals::all;

        if (angle < -90_degrees) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"latitude below minimum value"};
        }
        if (90_degrees < angle) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"latitude above maximum value"};
        }
    }
    constexpr void longitude::check()
    {
        // normalise to(-180, +180]
        auto d = angle / degrees;
        d = std::fmod(d + 180, 360);
        d -= std::copysign(180, d);
        if (d == -180) {
            // can occur when fmod returns +0
            d = 180;
        } else if (d == 0.0) {
            // preserve sign on prime meridian
            d = std::copysign(d, angle / degrees);
        }
        angle = d * degrees;
    }
}

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <sstream>

using namespace geo::literals::all;

TEST(latitude, error)
{
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(90_north);
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(90_south);
    EXPECT_THROW(91_north, std::invalid_argument);
    EXPECT_THROW(91_south, std::invalid_argument);

    EXPECT_THROW(90_north + 1e-10_degrees, std::invalid_argument);
    EXPECT_THROW(90_south - 1e-10_degrees, std::invalid_argument);
}

TEST(latitude, valid)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(30.0_north, 30_north);
    EXPECT_EQ(30.0_south, 30_south);
    EXPECT_EQ(30_south, geo::latitude(-30));
    EXPECT_NE(30_north, 30_south);
    EXPECT_EQ(0_north, 0_south);

    EXPECT_LT(40_south, 30_south);
    EXPECT_LT(30_north, 40_north);
    EXPECT_LT(30_south, 30_north);

    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<geo::angle_t>(40_north), 40_degrees);
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<geo::angle_t>(40_south), -40.0_degrees);

    EXPECT_EQ(30.0_north, 10_south + 40_degrees);
    EXPECT_EQ(30_north - 10.0_south, 40.0_degrees);

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << 10_north << ' ' << 5.5_south;
    EXPECT_EQ(os.str(), "10°N 5.5°S");
}

TEST(longitude, valid)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(30.0_east, 30_east);
    EXPECT_EQ(30.0_west, 30_west);
    EXPECT_NE(30_east, 30_west);
    // equivalence
    EXPECT_EQ(60_east, 300_west);
    EXPECT_EQ(300_east, 60_west);
    // edge cases
    EXPECT_EQ(0_east, 0_west);
    EXPECT_EQ(180_east, 180_west);
    EXPECT_EQ(360_east, 360_west);

    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<geo::angle_t>(120_east), 120_degrees);
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<geo::angle_t>(120_west), -120.0_degrees);

    EXPECT_EQ(120.0_east, 120.0_west - 120_degrees);

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << 175_east << ' ' << 25.5_west;
    EXPECT_EQ(os.str(), "175°E 25.5°W");
}


Consider deducing this instead of CRTP
Simplifying the general structure of your ordinate types, what you have is basically this:
template<typename Derived>
struct ordinate
{
    auto as_derived() -> Derived& { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }

    angle_t angle;

    // just picked a random operator
    auto operator+=(angle_t addend) -> Derived&
    {
        angle += addend;
        as_derived().check();
        return as_derived();
    }
};

struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
{
    auto check() { ... }
};

As of C++23, explicit object parameters can make this pattern much simpler, and more efficient:
// No longer a template!
//
// Also reduces code duplication, because there is no longer need for
// ordinate<latitude> and ordinate<longitude>... it's just ordinate.
struct ordinate
{
    // Don't need this anymore!
    //auto as_derived() -> Derived& { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }

    angle_t angle;

    // This is now a template with an explicit object parameter
    template<typename Self>
    auto operator+=(this Self&& self, angle_t addend) -> Self&
    {
        self.angle += addend;   // unfortunately, no implicit this, so need to "self." qualify everything
        self.check();           // note that value category (const, etc.) is correctly deduced
        return self;
    }
};

// No curious recurrence!
struct latitude : public ordinate
{
    auto check() { ... }
};

On the other hand… there is one reason why CRTP might be the right solution in this case:
Beware of down-casting in the constructor
Again, here is general structure:
template<typename Derived>
struct ordinate
{
    auto as_derived() -> Derived& { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }

    angle_t angle;

    ordinate(angle_t angle)
        : angle{angle}
    {
        as_derived().check();
    }
};

struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
{
    auto check() { ... }
};

In the ordinate constructor, you down-cast the ordinate to Derived (in as_derived()), and then call a member function of the down-casted type (.check()). The problem is that when the base class constructor is running, the derived class does not yet exist. So you are calling a member function of an object that hasn’t been constructed yet.
There is a simple fix here, though: just make the check function a static member function. Then you don’t need an object:
template<typename Derived>
struct ordinate
{
    angle_t angle;

    ordinate(angle_t angle)
        : angle{angle}
    {
        Derived::check(angle);
    }
};

struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
{
    static auto check(angle_t) { ... }
};

I’ve actually used this pattern a lot, and I’ve found it handy to make the validation function public, so that client code can validate a value without having to construct the type.
I’ve also found it handy to have a validation function that doesn’t necessarily throw, so that, again, client code can check whether a value is valid before diving in. This is especially useful in a UI where the user can enter a value. If the UI code is just dealt an exception, they don’t necessarily know that it was caused by an invalid value… it could have been a memory error after all, or anything else. Also, it’s clunky to actually suss out what was really wrong from an exception to give the user informative feedback. So a public, non-throwing validation function is actually a useful API.
// Utility function to unwrap expected values with system_error
// error codes enumerations.
template<typename T>
concept system_error_enumeration =
    std::is_enum_v<T>
    and std::is_error_code_enum<T>
    and requires(T e) { { make_error_code(e) } -> std::same_as<std::error_code>; }
;

template<typename T, system_error_enumeration E>
constexpr auto validate(std::expected<T, E> result)
{
    if (not result)
        throw std::system_error{make_error_code(result.error())};

    return *result;
}

template<typename Derived>
struct ordinate
{
    angle_t angle;

    ordinate(angle_t angle)
        : angle{validate(Derived::validate_value(angle))}
    {}
};

struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
{
    enum class invalid_value_errc
    {
        no_error,
        below_minimum,
        above_maximum
    };
    // make invalid_value_errc a system_error enumeration...

    static auto validate_value(angle_t angle) -> std::expected<angle_t, invalid_value_errc>
    {
        using namespace geo::literals::all;

        if (angle < -90_degrees)
            return std::unexpected{invalid_value_errc::below_minimum};
        if (90_degrees < angle)
            return std::unexpected{invalid_value_errc::above_maximum};

        return angle;
    }
};

// Client code can do validation checks without having to deal with exceptions:
auto lat_val = latitude::validate_value(get_input_from_ui_text_box_or_whatever());
if (not lat_val)
{
    switch (lat_val.error())
    {
    case latitude::invalid_value_errc::below_minimum:
        inform_user_value_is_below_minimum();
        // ... etc. ...
    }
}

Or if you don’t want to use <system_error>…:
template<typename Derived>
struct ordinate
{
    angle_t angle;

    ordinate(angle_t angle)
        : angle{Derived::validate_value(angle)}
    {}
};

struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
{
    enum class invalid_value_errc
    {
        no_error,
        below_minimum,
        above_maximum
    };

    static auto check_value(angle_t angle) -> std::expected<angle_t, invalid_value_errc>
    {
        using namespace geo::literals::all;

        if (angle < -90_degrees)
            return std::unexpected{invalid_value_errc::below_minimum};
        if (90_degrees < angle)
            return std::unexpected{invalid_value_errc::above_maximum};

        return angle;
    }

    static auto validate_value(angle_t angle) -> angle_t
    {
        auto value = check_value(std::move(angle));
        if (not value)
        {
            switch (value.error())
            {
            case invalid_value_errc::below_maximum:
                throw std::invalid_argument{"latitude below minimum value"};
            // ... etc. ...
            }
        }

        return *value;
    }
};

Consider a non-checking constructor
There are situations where you know an angle value is already validated, which makes the cost of validation superfluous.
For example:
        constexpr auto operator+(angle_t addend) const
        {
            return Derived(angle) += addend;
        }

There is no point running the checks in that construction. You already know the angle must be valid.
And this can come up when client code runs the checks themselves, if you make the validation function public:
// Assume check() returns a std::expected...
auto lat_val = latitude::check(get_input_from_ui_text_box_or_whatever());
if (lat_val)
{
    // At this point, we already know the value in lat_val is kosher,
    // so there is no need to run the checks again.
    return latitude{*lat_val};
}
else
{
    // Figure out what the error was, and inform the user.
}

For this I’ve often used tagged constructors, with tags that loudly announce “I realize this is risky, but I know what I’m doing”:
struct unchecked_t
{
    constexpr explicit unchecked_t() noexcept = default;
};

inline constexpr auto unchecked = unchecked_t{};

template<typename Derived>
struct ordinate
{
    ordinate(angle_t angle)
        : ordinate{unchecked, Derived::check(angle)}
    {}

    ordinate(unchecked_t, angle_t angle)
        : angle{angle}
    {}
};

// Regular initialization:
auto lat = latitude{42.0};
// "I realize this is risky but I know what I'm doing" initialization:
auto lat = latitude{unchecked, 42.0};

Miscellaneous other stuff
invalid_argument versus domain_error
In your latitude value checks, if the angle value is out of range, you throw std::invalid_argument. That’s not wrong… but there may be a “more right” option.
std::domain_error means “this function is a mathematical operation of some kind, and you gave me a value that doesn’t work for it”, which is a little more specific than just “you gave me a value that doesn’t work for this function”. So that’s one point in its favour.
The other point is that sometimes the error isn’t really that the argument is invalid. Consider 89_north + 5_degrees. Which argument in that operation is invalid? Is either argument truly invalid? 89°N is a perfectly cromulent latitude, and 5° is a perfectly cromulent angle. I would argue that both arguments are perfectly valid… it’s just that the operation on both arguments doesn’t work, and it doesn’t work because it goes outside of the operation’s valid domain. Thus: std::domain_error.
Trust in operator rewriting
    template<typename Derived>
    class ordinate
    {
        // ... [snip] ...

        constexpr bool operator==(const Derived& other) const
        {
            return angle == other.angle;
        }
        constexpr bool operator!=(const Derived& other) const
        {
            return angle != other.angle;
        }

There is no need to explicitly write operator!=. a != b will automatically be rewritten as not (a == b).
Comparison woes
    // Latitude unit
    // Valid range: 90°S to 90°N
    // Latitudes are strongly ordered from south to north
    struct latitude : public ordinate<latitude>
    {
        friend ordinate_base;

        using ordinate<latitude>::ordinate;

        // order relation makes sense for latitude but not longitude
        constexpr auto operator<=>(const latitude& other) const
        {
            // Boost units lack three-way comparisons :(
            return angle < other.angle ? std::strong_ordering::less
                : other.angle < angle ? std::strong_ordering::greater
                : std::strong_ordering::equal;
        }

While it’s true that Boost.Units lacks three-way comparison support, the quantity type does have the .value() accessor:
constexpr auto operator<=>(latitude const& other)
{
    return angle.value() <=> other.angle.value();
}

However, this will give a different result to what you have… and that’s a good thing, because floating point comparisons are not strongly-ordered. At best they are weakly-ordered, because of the existence of negative zero: even when positive and negative zero compare equal (as they do in C++), they are still distinct values, and thus only equivalent.
Actually, that’s something you should lean into. Right now, the following code:
std::cout << 0.0_north << '\n';
std::cout << 0.0_south << '\n';

… would print:
0°N
0°N

… which is… fine, I guess.
But consider if instead of:
constexpr latitude operator ""_south(long double x) { return latitude{-static_cast<double>(x) * degrees}; }

… you did:
// Note the position of the negative operator!
constexpr latitude operator ""_south(long double x) { return latitude{static_cast<double>(-x) * degrees}; }

… then you would get:
0°N
0°S

… which seems more correct to me.
This is because your printing code (correctly, IMO) uses std::signbit(), which can distinguish between positive and negative zero.
The two latitudes would still compare equal, because 0.0 == -0.0, and would still behave equivalently in pretty much all mathematical operations. But they would print distinctly, which is nice.
But back to:
constexpr auto operator<=>(latitude const& other)
{
    return angle.value() <=> other.angle.value();
}

Since we’re ultimately comparing doubles here, this is not only not weakly-ordered, it is not even ordered at all. But I don’t think that’s what you want. I presume you don’t want “NaN°N” to be a valid latitude.
So here’s what I suggest. First, when validating your latitude values, reject all unordered values:
    constexpr void latitude::check()
    {
        using namespace geo::literals::all;

        if (angle < -90_degrees) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"latitude below minimum value"};
        }
        if (90_degrees < angle) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"latitude above maximum value"};
        }

        // Basically:
        if ((angle.value() <=> 0.0) == std::partial_ordering::unordered)
            throw std::invalid_argument{"latitude value is invalid"};
    }

Now you know for a fact that the angle value is ordered. So your comparison can be:
constexpr auto operator<=>(latitude const& other)
{
    switch (angle.value() <=> other.angle.value())
    {
    case std::partial_ordering::less:
        return std::weak_ordering::less;
    case std::partial_ordering::equivalent:
        return std::weak_ordering::equivalent;
    case std::partial_ordering::greater:
        return std::weak_ordering::greater;
    default:
        std::unreachable();
    }
}

I’d also add that it’s a little weird that latitudes are ordered but longitudes are not. By convention, positive latitudes are north while negative latitudes are south… but northern latitudes are not actually “greater” in any mathematical or logical sense than southern latitudes. I mean, you could argue that if the equator is the basis or zero point, then deviations from it can be “greater” based on the magnitude, so 3°N is greater than 2°N and 3°S is greater than 2°S… but you can’t get from there to the idea that 2°N is greater than 2°S without the convention that northward is “positive” and southward is “negative”.
But if you do accept that convention, then there is a similar convention for longitudes: positive longitudes are eastward, and negative longitudes are westward (with the prime meridian as the basis). So if latitudes can be ordered… why not longitudes?
I get that there are issues with raw calculations using longitudes due to the discontinuity at the anti-meridian (what happens if you are at 170°E and you add 20°?), but there are also issues with latitudes: what happens if you are at 80°N and you add 20°. Or put another way: adding 9° to 80°N gives you a latitude (89°N) that is greater than 80°N (89°N > 80°N)… but adding 21° to 80°N gives you a latitude (101°N → 79°N) that is less than 80°N (79°N < 80°N)? If you can tolerate discontinuity and wraparound with latitude (or if you plan to detect and throw if it happens), why not with longitude?
(And yes, I am aware that some USians use an opposite convention for longitude, so that all coordinates in the US are “positive”. But the international standard is eastward positive.)
consteval all the things!
I would suggest making all UDL operators consteval, not constexpr. With constexpr, the UDL functions could still be run at run-time:
auto func(long double angle)
{
    return operator ""_north(angle);
}

… which is probably not something you want to allow.
I would not only make all the UDLs consteval, I would take advantage of the compile-time checks to verify that the parameter is within range:
consteval auto safe_cast_to_double(long double x)
{
    // I don’t bother to check for infinities here, but you probably
    // should in the general case.
    //
    // Or you could just use boost::numeric_cast since you're already
    // using Boost.

    if ((x > std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) or (x < std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()))
        throw std::domain_error{"value too large for double"};
    if (std::abs(x) < std::numeric_limits<double>::min())
        throw std::domain_error{"value too small for double"};

    return static_cast<double>(d);
}

consteval latitude operator ""_north(long double x) { return latitude{safe_cast_to_double(x) * degrees};  }

Beware of IOstreams shenanigans
So your latitude stream inserter is:
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const latitude& x)
{
    auto const d = x.angle / degrees;
    return os << std::abs(d) << "°" << (std::signbit(d) ? 'S' : 'N');
}

The longitude one is basically the same thing.
Do be aware that writing the stream inserter this way makes it sensitive to locale shenanigans. In particular, the angle value could be printed in unpredictable ways. Maybe this is what you want, maybe not.
Writing the stream inserter this way makes it sensitive to other shenanigans as well. For example. if someone sets the stream width, it will only be applied to the angle value, and possibly separated from the rest of the string.
For example:
std::cout.width(5);
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::left);
std::cout << 0.0_north << "latitude";

… prints:
0    °Nlatitude

I would presume you want it to print:
0°N  latitude

The general form for a stream inserter is:
class T
{
    template<typename Char, typename Traits>
    friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, T const& v)
        -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
    {
        if (o)
        {
            auto oss = std::ostringstream{};

            // If you want non-locale-aware behaviour:
            oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());
            // ... or if you want locale-aware behaviour:
            oss.imbue(o.getloc());

            // Copy any other formatting flags you want to be relevant.

            // Do the formatting.

            o << std::move(oss).str().c_str();
        }

        return o;
    }
};

You don’t need to make it a template—you could just use std::ostream—but you get full support of all character and traits types for free anyway, so you might as well.
For just basic formatting, you could do:
template<typename Char, typename Traits>
friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, latitude const& v)
    -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
{
    if (o)
    {
        auto oss = std::ostringstream{};

        // If you want non-locale-aware behaviour:
        oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());
        // ... or if you want locale-aware behaviour:
        oss.imbue(o.getloc());

        auto const d = x.angle / degrees;
        oss << std::abs(d) << "°" << (std::signbit(d) ? 'S' : 'N');

        o << std::move(oss).str().c_str();
    }

    return o;
}

But for more advanced formatting options you will have to be cagier. In particular, if you want to support std::ios_base::internal alignment, you’ll have to do a bit of work.
I would suggest that the stream inserter should be locale-aware, as this is what one would expect by default. If someone wants non-locale-aware behaviour, they can just imbue the stream with the classic locale. You’ll get most of the way there just by default, because the default num_put behaviour will work for the angle value. After that you just need to make the degree sign and direction suffix locale-aware, if they need to be.
But any more than that… probably not worth it. IOStreams is a dead-end technology. You could implement very advanced custom formatting with std::ios_base::xalloc() and std::ios_base::pword() and so on. But 1) learning how to do it is pointless because 2) no one’s going to use it. It is sensible and worthwhile to support existing, standard IOStreams formatting options (including locale-awareness). But for anything beyond that, std::format() is the future.
I would suggest the general strategy for adding formatting support to a type should be in three stages.
First, start with a basic, non-locale-aware, constexpr formatting function: to_string() or to_chars() or both. In this case, you could use std::to_chars() internally to format the angle, then just tack on the suffix. This alone will be enough for more than 90% of use cases.
Second, implement your IOStreams inserter. Start simple, perhaps by just calling the above mentioned to_string() or to_chars() as a first pass. Then add functionality: locale-awareness, formatting-savvyness, and so on.
And then finally, std::format() support, with a custom format language to allow users to specify:

whether they want the N/S/E/W suffix
whether they want the degree sign (because it’s not ASCII)
whether they want 2°S printed as “2°S” or “−2°N”

… and so on. There should be very little code duplication, because the only difference between longitude and latitude is the letter suffixes.
People often underestimate the difficulty of adding really good output and formatting support for a type. Output is usually just slapped on as an afterthought. But doing it right, and rigorously testing that it’s right, is a project unto itself, even for very simple types.
And then… how about implementing parsing support, for inputting latitude/longitude values? That’s a whole other level of challenge, and yet again, almost a separate project in its own right.

I'd not seen deduced-this as an alternative to CRTP before.  Thank you for teaching me that.
